# unresolved external symbol error when using static library

Tags: c++, templates, header

I am trying to make static library for solving probability and stats. 
I am getting LNK2019 unresolved external symbol error when running my code. I think the program isnt detecting the definitions of function from the .cpp file and i dont get the issue here. Also i have given the main file directions for the library so no issue there. I am new in using headers and templates so kindly help. The error occurs when the program calls the constructor for the object:

```
> LNK2019   unresolved external symbol "public: __thiscall ProbnStatslib::means<float>::means<float>(void)"(??0?$means@M@ProbnStatslib@@QAE@XZ) referenced in function_main
```

### **Header file:**

```
// .h file
#ifndef PROBNSTATSLIB_H
#define PROBNSTATSLIB_H
#include<iostream>
#include<vector>

namespace ProbnStatslib
{
    template<typename any>
    class means 
    {
    private:
        std::vector<any> xi_mean;
        int N;
    public:
        means();
        void initializer(int size);
        void CalcMean();

    };

}
#endif
```

**The .cpp**

```
// .cpp
#include<iostream>
#include"ProbnStatslib.h"
#include<vector>
using namespace std;
namespace ProbnStatslib
{
    template<typename any>
    means<any>::means()
    {
        cout << "object constructed" << endl;
        cout << "Enter number of ouccrances:" << endl;
        cin >> this->N;
        initializer(this->N);
    }
    template<typename any>
    void means<any>::initializer(int size)
    {
        cout << "Enter event values or Xi of size:"<< size << endl;

        /*for (any value : xi_mean)
        {
            cin >> this->xi_mean;
        }*/
    }
    template<typename any>
    void means<any>::CalcMean() {
        cout << "Calculating" << endl;
    }

}
```

**The main file:**

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include "ProbnStatslib.h"
using namespace std;
using namespace ProbnStatslib;
int main()
{
    means<float> myobj;
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: `template<typename any>` combined with `using namespace std` will probably cause you problems at some point due to a conflict with `std::any`

Comment: Thanks for pointing to the solution and the tip.